# CakePHP Html->link and Form->end

Tags: cakephp

I have this link that I use to for my modal

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link('Create Schedule', '#', array('id' => 'createSchedule', 'class' => 'btn btn-success', 'role' => 'button', )); 
?>
```

How do I convert it to $this->Form->end() format?

Thank you!

Comment: You question doesn't make sense. HtmlHelper::link() and FormHelper::end() generate different tags. They are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this also

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->button("Create Schedule", array("id" => "createSchedule", "class" => "btn btn-success", "type" => "submit"));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

or you could also do this

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->submit("Create Schedule", array("id" => "createSchedule", "class" => "btn btn-success"));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
    $options = array(
        'label' => 'Create Schedule',
        'id'    => 'createSchedule',
        'class' => 'btn btn-success'
    );
    echo $this->Form->end($options);
?>
```